# Please explain to me why this simple C program with if statements doesn't work?

Tags: c, if-statement

I've just learned about if statements and tried to make some sort of calculator, but it won't work. It asks you to enter an operation (for now only addition works), and then it asks for two integers. It's super simple, but it won't work. The error may be obvious to you guys, but I just don't see it. Please help! Here's the code:

```
int main()
{
int operation;
int addition;
float firstNumber; 
float secondNumber;
printf("Type in an operation.\n");
scanf(" %s", operation);


if(operation = addition){
printf("Please, enter an integer.\n");
scanf(" %f", &firstNumber);

printf("Please, enter a second integer.\n");
scanf(" %f", &secondNumber);

printf("Answer: %d", firstNumber + secondNumber);
}else{
printf("Sorry, only addition works..");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `=` != `==`. Assignment is not comparison. Also, using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while the value is indeterminate is undefined behavior.

Comment: EOF is right.  You're assigning `addition` to `operation` rather than comparing them.  But even if you fix that, you still have a problem.  You're never assigning anything to `addition`, so your compare won't work.

Comment: I see. So what should I do instead? Is it even possible to do what I was intending using only if and else statements? Thanks for answering.

Comment: `int operation; int addition;` --> `char operation; char addition = '+';`..`scanf(" %s", operation); if(operation = addition){` --> `scanf(" %c", &operation); if(operation == addition){`

Comment: You should change your code to use the equality operator and assign a value to `addition`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for the help everybody.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. It skips straight to "Sorry, only addition works.." But thanks anyway!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. Your title should be something that is useful to future readers who see it in a search result. Imagine you're trying to solve a problem, and you do a search here and find many questions with a title similar to yours (*my code doesn't work, why won't my code work, explain this non-working code*) - what use would that be to you? Your title should describe a specific problem or question. Your only learning about if statements yesterday does not mean you don't have to ask a specific question here.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Will do that right away.

Answer (score 2):

Why should your code work?

```
int operation; 
/* int for storing a string? huh? 
 * or were you thinking about function pointers ?
 * Normally you would use a char[]
 */


scanf(" %s", operation); 
/* Using %s specifier looks weird .
 * Also scanf is reading into operation and not &operation
 * So is having a space in the in the beginning of the format string.
 */

int addition; 
 /* Automatic variables are not initialized as per the standard
  * But what about the type?
  * Were you intending to do something like char addition[]="addition"
  */

if(operation = addition)  
/* If you somehow manage to get to this point 
 * you have another problem you do an assignment in the statement using =
 * You should have been  using ==
 */
```

Comment: Also...`scanf` is reading into `operation` and not `&operation`.

Comment: Not sure if you read the entire question but I learned about if statements yesterday. I have been programming in C for one week. Your answer wasn't helpful at all, you are trying too hard to sound smart. Please stop.

Comment: @MatheusDutra : I agree everybody has a first time but I didn't try anything smart here. I just pointed out the errors in code.. It's up to you how you take it. No regrets !! And happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
wrong:

if(operation = addition)
{
};

correct:

if(operation == addition)
{
};
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, that only solves half the problem.